# How to give a parameter a type containing a list of keys from another type and be able to insert any other STRING value out of the keys

Tags: typescript

i would like to be able to type the parameter of a function according to a list of keys of a type, but also i would like to give freedom to insert any other **STRING** value which is not included in "keys of the type", **but it needs to keep the autocomplete of the keys on.**

The method receives 2 arguments, and i have typed it so that the second argument will be required depended on the first argument value, and depended on the first argument value, the second argument will be typed accordingly, as you can see below:

```
type Settings = {
  AddPaymentInfo?: string
  AddToCart?: number
  Lead?: boolean
  Purchase: Date
}

function track<T extends keyof Settings>(
  ...args: undefined extends Settings[T]
    ? [pixelCmd: T, settings?: Settings[T]]
    : [pixelCmd: T, settings: Settings[T]]
) {
  // do stuff
}
```

If i change the method to this:

```
function track<T extends keyof Settings>(
  ...args: undefined extends Settings[T]
    ? [pixelCmd: T | string, settings?: Settings[T]]
    : [pixelCmd: T | string, settings: Settings[T]]
) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Typescript will stop complaining that i have passed a value that is not included in keysof Settings, but i will lose the autocomplete for the keys. Ah, and also, if passed a value which is not included in keys of Settings, the second argument (settings) should have the standard object type (settings?: object) and be optional.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You might find the [LiteralUnion](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/HEAD/source/literal-union.d.ts) type from [`type-fest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/type-fest) useful.